# Using functions outside main() C

Tags: c, function, debugging, parameters, syntax-error

I am trying to run the code down below but it is giving me a `error: void value not ignored as it ought to be`. I also get `warning: ‘return’ with a value, in function returning void`

The code below is meant to multiply 10 and 20 within the `multiplytwoNumbers` and then return the result to be printed in the `main()` function.

```
void multiplytwoNumbers(int x, int y)
{
    int result = x*y;
    return result;
}

int main(void)
{
    int result;
    result= multiplytwoNumbers(10,20);

    printf("The multipication of %d and %d results in %d\n", 10,20,result);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `void multiplytwoNumbers` -> `int multiplytwoNumbers`

Comment: If you search for error messages and warnings, you often find the solution to your problem

Comment: I reopened it, because none of the dupes were good duplicates. This question had kind of the opposite solution.

Comment: Oh, OP didn't you get the warning "warning: ‘return’ with a value, in function returning void"? You should have

Answer (score 2):

```
void multiplytwoNumbers(int x, int y)
```

The error is pretty much what the compiler tells you: you can't return an `int` for a `void` function.

For your case,

```
result= multiplytwoNumbers(10,20);
```

The result type should be something like `long long` because you just use `int` it could overflow if both `x` and `y` is approaching the `int` limit. So you should change to:

```
long long multiplytwoNumbers(int x, int y)
{
    long long result = x*y;
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to return a calculated value from a function with return type 'void'. I suggest you change `void multiplytwoNumbers(int x, int y)` into `int multiplytwoNumbers(int x, int y)` and see what that brings you!